# I never thought that I would fall in love like I do or like I am?

Tags: grammar

I never thought that I will fall in love like I am or like I do?

1)I never thought that I will fall in love like **I am**.

2) I never thought that I will fall in love like **I do**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:

- I never thought that I would fall in love like I did.
- I never thought that I would be falling in love like I am.
- I never thought that I would be in love like I am.
- I never thought that I would love her like I do.

We need someone else to add some explanation, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you. regarding to the 1st option, if I say "I did" it something that belong to the past, while I am talking about the moment. On the other hand if I use the 2nd option then the meaning of "falling in love" is gone. What do you recommend?:)

Comment: If you want to keep it in the present, you would have to say "I never thought that I would be falling in love like I am." I'm not an expert. I know "what" but I don't necessarily know "why".

Comment: Thank you. You absolutely helped me. The explanation for why is not necessary in this case. If you can add the last option (would be falling in love like I am) to your answer, it will be great, because the answer is actually in the comment at the moment and I would like to choose it as the best answer.

Comment: @Assiduous Done, but to be an accepted answer, it really needs some explanatory notes and that I cannot supply. Anyway, glad to have helped.